# Does "pop out" has the meaning of "born"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

From the [Jobs' speech in Stanford](http://news.stanford.edu/news/2005/june15/jobs-061505.html), there is a sentence:

> Except that when I popped out they decided at the last minute that they really wanted a girl.

You can see there is a phrase *pop out* and I understand it as "born". But I can't find such explanations in the dictionary.

So does it have the meaning of *born*, or just can be inferred from the context? When can I use it to express *born* and shall I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a life form that emerges into the world by being born or hatched, yes, "pop out" is a colloquial equivalent.

However, inert objects can "pop out" as well such as a cork "pops out" of a bottle.